# how to deal with GET parameters in facebook sharer

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to share a link on facebook using its simple Sharer.
I'm passing some parameters in this way:

```
title="Share this article/post/whatever on Facebook"    
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
s=100
&p[url]=http://www.mypage.com/index.php?firstID=1&secondID=2
//etc.
```

but it's only partially working because it only take the firstID but not the second.
My guess is that Facebook thinks that secondID is its own, but it can't use it and it discards the param.
Any guess on how I can escape them?

Comment: You are using `sharer.php` to share your link. If that is correct then you should encode your URL before passing.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about that. I searched and found PHP's rawurlencode, it did the job. Thank you.

Comment: I have added it as the answer, please accept it if that helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `sharer.php` to share the page you should encode the URL so that it is used by it in appropriate manner or else it might take the parameters like your `secondID` as its own parameter and would render the URL incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `rawurlencode()` on the shared url:

```
title="Share this article/post/whatever on Facebook"    
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?
s=100
&p[url]=<?=rawurlencode('http://www.mypage.com/index.php?firstID=1&secondID=2')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works.  Facebook does not directly accept URL with parameters within your local page.  It strips them off in it's process.  If you are writing your own code in PHP, you can get around this problem by encoding the parameters and then attaching this encoded string to the end of the page URL.

This works in a WordPress environment as well, if you are using shortcodes to populate the page.

The code snippet I came up with is this:

```
 // When generating a URL for display, encode the parameters within the standard URL
 $PageURL       = "https://yourdomain/page";
 $EncodedParams = urlencode('param1='.<YOUR VALUE> . '&param1='.<YOUR VALUE>);
 $URLPath       = $PageURL . '?' . $EncodedParams . '#';
```

Now on the page in question

```
 // This find the page you are currently displaying
 $protocol      = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || 
 $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
 $url           = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Retrieve the parameters from the URL
$EncodedParams = substr($url, strrpos($url, '?' )+1);
$DecodeParams  = urldecode ($EncodedParams);

$Params        = explode('&', $DecodeParams);
$temp          = explode('param1=', $Params[0]);
$Param1       = $temp[1];
$temp          = explode('param2=', $Params[1]);
$Param2        = $temp[1];
```

Param1 and Param2 can now be used in the code for further definition.  The trick is all about encoding.